# How to extract the issue data using google script and crbug

Tags: google-apps-script

Using google script i want to connect to crbug i.e. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues
and extract the data.

please let me know how i can connect to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues this url using google script and extract the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `importxml()` method to extract the content of the page inside google spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Urlfetchapp.fetch() method to extract the content of the page inside Google Scripts and then use regular expressions to extract links and other data from the fetched page.

Comment: Amit, I have to fire different queriers, if i get access to https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues so i can fire the different queries in order to extract the data.